# TFDSQLiteBackup - Can you copy the password of the open database when the password is not known?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, c++builder, firedac

When using `TFDSQLiteBackup` to create a backup of an open and connected SQLite database, is there a way to copy the password over to the new database when you don't know the password and don't want to ask the user for it?

If not, can you just `CopyFile()` the open SQLite database?  Anything that should be done before doing that?

Comment: Copying the SQLite file alone should only be done when it is only accessed by reading from it. Otherwise just have a look which additional files are automatically created once the file is in use (and which disappear once the access ends). As per scenario you may want to copy the additional files, too.